# virtualbox not showing up in applications after installing package

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I recently installed **VirtualBox** via the official website using the provided `.deb` installer. It installed and showed up within the *Application Menu*. However, after starting up a new iso it output an error that rendered **VirtualBox** useless (which I couldn't seem to fix at all). So I completely purged and installed the latest version through the *Terminal*.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox=5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1
```

After installing though, I noticed that the application does not show up in the *Application Menu*. I have no idea why I can't seem to find VirtualBox at all, so this is very annoying.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you run Virtualbox from terminal using `virtualbox` as a command? And what is the output of `apt list --installed | grep virtualbox` and `dpkg --get-selections | grep virtualbox`?

Comment: `Command 'virtualbox' not found`. List is `virtualbox/bionic-updates,now 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
virtualbox-dkms/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]`

Comment: What do you get after `find /usr/bin/virtualbox`?

Answer (score 0):

You have just installed the Virtualbox base binary. You need to install virtualbox-qt to open it up. 
Just

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-qt=5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.1
```

is enough.